# Export custom class or function in React-Native

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6

how to export and use your custom made class or function in React-Native?

i have created a file named "**customdata.js**", which contains a function that returns array data. When i import a function from that file, i can't retrieve a returned value. it only returns [Function: function-name] in a console log

Here is my code below:

**customdata.js**

```
export function clienList(){
  let clients = [
    'D4 Soweto',
    'Road Freight Provident Fund',
    'Internal Cafe'
  ];
  return clients;
}
```

**row.js**

```
//import from customdata
import {clienList} from './customdata';

//ListView
const elems = ['something'];
const source = new ListView.DataSource({
                   rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
                });

export default class Row extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dataSource: source.cloneWithRows(elems),
      pickerValue:'Sonke'
    };
  };
  render() {
    console.log(clienList);
```

**My console log**

02-20 12:21:30.853  2844  3730 I ReactNativeJS: [Function: clienList]

Comment: You the Best!! Thanks a lot, wish i could upvote this answer :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just call that function. As you can see in the console log you are importing the function, in order for the function to return you a value you need to call it first `clienList()`:

```
import { clienList } from './customdata';
clienList(); // this will return the value
clienList // this will return the function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir ! :D

Comment: have a look at http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_classes.html to learn more about the classes